# Pass props to a nested Tabnavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I am working with react native for 3 months now and i have this problem now for several days without any solution.

The Problem:
I have a nested TabNavigator inside a StackNavigator. Both of these navigators are inside a stateless component:

```
const MyStackNav = StackNavigator({
  Tabs:{
    screen: TabNavigator({
        Tab1: { screen: TabScreen1},
        Tab2: { screen: TabScreen2},
        Tab3: { screen: TabScreen3},
        ...(CONDITION ? { Tab4: {
          screen: TabScreen4
        }} : {})
      })
    }
  StackScreen1:{
    screen: StackScreenOne,
  },
  StackScreen2:{
    screen: StackScreenTwo,
  },
})
```

Calling of the component:

```
class MainApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      condition: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyStackNav/>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I pass the condition from my class `MainApp` to the condition variable inside the `MyNavStack` component for the conditional rendering?
So Tab4 should only be rendered if CONDITION is true.

And the second question would be:
How can I pass a prop from my class `MainApp` to, for example, the first tab screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even I have the same problem did you solve it?

Comment: No. I changed the layout so that the conditional rendering is happening inside of the tab, not the tab itself... It´s not what i actually wanted, but it´s currently working. But this problem is still on my TODO-List... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can give you `MyStackNav` a property like: `<MyStackNav condition={this.state.condition} />`

In the `MyStackNav` you could say:

```
const MyStackNav = props => StackNavigator({
  Tabs:{
    screen: TabNavigator({
        Tab1: { screen: TabScreen1},
        Tab2: { screen: TabScreen2},
        Tab3: { screen: TabScreen3},
        ...(props.condition? { Tab4: {
          screen: TabScreen4
        }} : {})
      })
    }
  StackScreen1:{
    screen: StackScreenOne,
  },
  StackScreen2:{
    screen: StackScreenTwo,
  },
})
```

You don't need to create a `React.component`, to pass down props.

You can also expand it a bit, in case you'd like to do a little bit more in your component:

```
 const MyStackNav = (props) => {
         const { condition } = props;
         return StackNavigator({
             Tabs: {
                 screen: TabNavigator({
                     Tab1: {
                         screen: TabScreen1
                     },
                     Tab2: {
                         screen: TabScreen2
                     },
                     Tab3: {
                         screen: TabScreen3
                     },
                     ...(condition ? {
                         Tab4: {
                             screen: TabScreen4
                         }
                     } : {})
                 })
             }
             StackScreen1: {
                 screen: StackScreenOne,
             },
             StackScreen2: {
                 screen: StackScreenTwo,
             },
         })
}
```

Comment: I´ve already tried it this way and i always get the following error message:
"MyNavStack(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

The root of this error message is in the mountComponent!

Comment: Try wrapping `StackNavigator` in e.g. `<span>`. So: `<span>{StackNavigator(/* stuff */)}</ span>`

Comment: So currently i am getting the following error message: "Expected a component class, got [object Object]".
The only solution i found to this is that classes have to start with a capital letter, which mine does...